# How to Embed Video Google Drive using Youtube Iframe

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed

I'm using this code but not working

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" width="100%" height="400" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwbA32qGbwr8TTdidmFMZnV3SDg/view" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

please help me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's will be conflict in that way, you can't force like that.

you can try on this `https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference`